# How to configure openMP for nested loops to keep the inner loop not parallelized?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following nested for loops. I want to parallelize the first loop but the second loop must NOT be parallelized. So I want that each thread executes the second loop in itself, which means that second loop must be special for each thread (for each "i" in the code).

How can I do that?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=k+1;i<row;i++){
        for (n=0;n<k;n++){
           // #pragma omp atomic
            dummy += L[i][n]*L[k][n];
            L[i][k] = (A[i][k] - dummy)/L[k][k];
        }
        dummy = 0;
    }
```

Comment: it won't be, parallel for applies to next for loop but not subsequent ...

Comment: but the result turns out to be wrong out of this loop. the second loop must suffer some form of intervention from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `omp parallel for` pragma applies only to the loop that follows it immediately. The `i` loop will be distributed between threads. Within each iteration of `i`, the `n` loop will be executed on the same thread. Your code already does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. But the result turns out to be completely different, so I thought multiple threads should be playing role in the second loop.

Comment: Well, your instinct to use omp atomic is correct - you are updating the shared variable dummy. You should use the OpenMP reduction clause for that though.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, your dummy variable is only used within the iteration, so I would declare it within the outer loop and set it to 0, before the start of the inner loop. No atomic pragma will be needed for that.

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code as you suggested. But the results are still different.

Comment: Another thing - the n loop variable is currently defined outside of the outer loop, which makes it shared between threads. You should define it either as part of the for loop (which is the preferred C++ style) or just before the inner loop. This may well be the cause of the problem.